# A program that supports different types of GPU

Tags: gpu, opencl

If i want to develop A program that supports different types of GPU.what should i do? I know that OPENCL can do this.but how OPENCL did this?

Comment: Hope someone can help me . appreciate you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCL is the best choice for vendor-independent GPU programming.
The way it works is runtime-compilation: You compile C++ to an executable and this executable contains the OpenCL C source code as text/string. When you run the executable on the CPU, it compiles the OpenCL C code specifically for the installed GPU. The OpenCL compiler is provided as part of the graphics driver. This way, you can copy the executable to another computer and there the contained OpenCL C code can compiled for a different GPU, all without having to recompile the executable.
This is similar to how Java works.

Comment: thank you very much❤.  If i want to solve Ax = b in different GPU and don't use OpenGL.is it possible?If its possible, how to achieve it？

Comment: Yes, you can use OpenCL to solve linear equations. This is in fact one of the most common algorithms and there are many existing implementations. See for example ViennaCL: http://viennacl.sourceforge.net/doc/manual-algorithms.html